# What is Discover traffic in Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console

I saw some traffic from "Discover" for a few days but later it back to zero again.

And I never got any traffic from "Discover" since 5/16/21.

What is this for?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discover is a feed-like product from Google where they show you a list of content that they think will interest you.  It appears to only be available on mobile through an app.  Here is [Google's announcement about it](https://blog.google/products/search/introducing-google-discover/).

When your site got discover traffic, somebody saw your site in their feeds.  Since this product is so new, it doesn't have many users yet. so sites are not getting consistent traffic from discover.

It also appears that this graph in Google Search console is some sort of test available only to some users.   None of my properties in GSC have a link to the performance report for Discover.